# How to copy certain file extensions given the input of the directory?

Tags: linux, shell

What I am trying to basically do with this shell script is to have the user input a directory via console and have the output be all of the .c files that are inside that directory and the sub-directories within it (the files are copied to the current location of the script).

```
rsync -va --include "*/" --include '*.c' --exclude '*' "$1/" .
```

However when I run the script (sh test.sh DirA) it copies all of the sub-directories within the $1 directory, with nothing inside them (not even the .c files). I want the output to not be the directories, but instead ONLY the .c files.

So if I were to ls in the current directory it should come out with a bunch of files like: file.c file1.c file2.c NOT dir1 dir2 dir3.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not Unix tech support.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply leave out `--exclude '*'`. As it occurs later on the command line, it is applied after a candidate file succeded the `--include '*.c'` test and causes any file to be rejected.

So, for simply copying any `.c` file within the given subtree to a hierarchy at current directory use a plain:

```
rsync -va --include '*.c' "$1" .
```

***EDIT:***

As `rsync` is all about copying and synchronizing hierarchies, it is the wrong tool for flattening hierarchies into a single directory. For such an operation you will need a command that is explicitly ignoring the source path for the target side (like plain `cp`).

E.g. in your case you could use:

```
find "$1" -name '*.c' -print0 | xargs -0 -I'{}' cp {} .
```

Comment: Data was being sent and retrieved, but the .c files were not moved anywhere. Am I perhaps using the rsync incorrectly? Should I be using -cp instead of -va?